# ADAL.NET: Using it to authenticate using javascript

Tags: javascript, adal

I recently happen to find this library:

http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/09/12/active-directory-authentication-library-adal-v1-for-net-general-availability/

This is a wonderful tool that is able to abstract away a lot of complexities of authenticating  against AAD.

I was wondering if it or any of it's known variations support authentication through Javascript.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: were you looking for a javascript .net binding, or a javascript version of ADAL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are actively working on a Javascript ADAL version, stay tuned!

Answer (score 1):

There is another add-on that seems to be supported through AZURE called [Auth0](https://auth0.com/).

Auth0 offers, seemingly plug and play, distrubited Security Authorization by just filling in a few variables.  The big downfall is the pricing.  But in general, it seems like there is a nice way for raw javascript to authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

1st: there are many libraries. You can check this to get started: http://adodson.com/hello.js/

2nd: Caution: it won't make much sense to have it from security point of view because of following reasons:

--> Since JavaScript will qualify under public client category therefore confidential client flow of OAuth code grant involving client secret is not possible (or better yet, doesn't make sense).

--> Your JavaScript will qualify for public client code flow. This will mean that you will expose at least your client ID and return URL to EVERYONE and this again isn't a good sign. Public clients are already weak in security and exposing client id will worsen it.

--> Also notice, you'll have cross site request issues.